# If else statement for PHP DateTime diff

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I am using meta_box value `(YmdHi)` and `current Date&time` to print time difference. And this code work for me.

Now additionally i want to print `Live` when 2 hours left to start Event.

**What mistake I 'm doing to print `if or else` currently this not work for me?**

```
$then = date( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_start_eventtimestamp', true ) ) ;
$then = new DateTime($then);
$now = new DateTime();
$sinceThen = $then->diff($now);

if ($sinceThen > 2 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS){
       echo $sinceThen->d.'days'; 
       echo $sinceThen->h.'hours'; 
       echo $sinceThen->i.'minutes';
 }
else{
        echo 'LIVE';
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$sinceThen` is a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) (that's what [`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) returns), so you're comparing a `int` with an `object`, which obviously gives you unexpected results. To get the difference in seconds, subtract both `DateTime` instances' timestamps (which you obtain with [`DateTime::getTimestamp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php)):

```
$then = date( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_start_eventtimestamp', true ) ) ;
$then = new DateTime($then);
$now = new DateTime();
$sinceThen = $then->diff($now);
$sinceThenInSeconds = $then->getTimestamp() - $now->getTimestamp();

if ($sinceThenInSeconds > 2 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS){
    echo $sinceThen->d.'days'; 
    echo $sinceThen->h.'hours'; 
    echo $sinceThen->i.'minutes';
}
else{
    echo 'LIVE';
}
```

Comment: Printed Live to correct place but Now date&time have problem only this show (dayshoursminutes)

Comment: Sorry, forgot you still used `$sinceThen`. I edited, try now!

Comment: How can i get two digit value always? if current out put is `2days2hours2min` change it to `02days02hours02min`.

Comment: @MuhammadArifKamboh use [`format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php#refsect1-dateinterval.format-parameters). Inside your `if` block, instead of those 3 `echo`s, paste this `echo $sinceThen->format("%D days, %H hours and %M minutes");`